# Dropbox - Android - How to login to dropbox without the user knowing they are using Dropbox?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am trying to develop an application that uses some sort of cloud storage. I thought dropbox would be perfect to use. I already have my app key and app secret.

In the example that they give for the DBRoulette, you go through an external GUI to login to Dropbox. For my app, I just want to log in behind the scenes with not having the user know that the cloud portion is Dropbox

Any suggestions to make this happen would be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to make direct network requests to [REST API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api) using your own account credentials. Though I won't recommend handing out your account credentials to public in your App's code. And saving user data without their consent and a formal privacy policy notice, is a bad practice.

Comment: is using dropbox a necessary here? Google Storage might be a better approach. most people have a google account, and you can login to google using an oauth. You don't need to explain to the user that actually you are using google storage.

Comment: Thanks for the update User117.
Rudy, that is also an option, but what I would like to do is save something (pictures or some type of log) so that anyone that has access can retrieve the files. Either out in the field or in the office via desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply not possible, at least not with the current public APIs that DropBox provides. I doubt that this will change any time soon, and that's a good thing.

Dropbox forces you to use Oauth for authentication and authorization and they have good reasons for that.

Most service providers that offer SDKs to allow third party apps to integrate with them use Oauth (Twitter,Dropbox,Linkedin,Google,SalesForce,.....).

An important part is that the user **always** needs to authorize the application to access the users data on their behalf.

This is always a manual step (in most cases only performed once) that the end-user needs to do. He always needs to click a button somewhere to explicitly give his/her permission.

It cannot be done silently in the background, just like you cannot silently send SMS text messages in Android without forcing the user to grant permission to do that.

Comment: I understand that the user should authorize the application. The user already logins into my app via a login screen, with the creds sent to a server (Different from dropbox), would there be some way to just do a login to dropbox at start up?

Comment: The login is not sufficient. The user needs to be logged in before he can authorize your app. The authorization step is a required step. So even if there is single-sign-on, the user would still need to go through the authorization screen in order for your app to retrieve an access token.